# How to put an input from an if statement back into the program

Tags: java

I am very new to coding but I was wondering why when I get an answer wrong in my math question it asks me to try again but then does not let me answer that question again. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
public class ComputerAssistedInstruction {
public static void main(String args[]) {
int exit = 1;   
System.out.println("LETS DO MATH!!!!!");
while(exit == 1) 
{
    int answer = 0;
    question(answer);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Would you like to exit? 1 to stay, 2 to exit.");
        exit = sc.nextInt();
}

if(exit != 1 || exit != 2)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("That is not an acceptable input. Try again.");
    exit = sc.nextInt();
}
if(exit == 2) 
{
    System.out.println("Goodbye");  
}
}
public static void question(long question)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int input;
    int answertrue;
    number1 = random.nextInt(10);
    number2 = random.nextInt(10);
    answertrue = number1 * number2;
    System.out.printf("%d*%d=", number1,number2);
        input = sc.nextInt();
    if(input == answertrue)
    {
        System.out.println("Goodjob!");
    }
    if(input != answertrue)
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry try again");
        System.out.printf("%d*%d=", number1,number2);
        input = sc.nextInt();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: I _does_ let you enter a response again, but it just basically ignores that response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few conventions that can optimize your code. I will show you a simple example that can help explain the while loop logic so that you can get the question to repeat if the answer is incorrect as you stated. There are ways to optimize this code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);//Create the scanner object 
boolean running = true; //Create a boolean "flag" for the while loop. 
int answer = 0; //Initial answer set to 0

while(running) { //program "flag". Should run so long as running == true
        System.out.println("Welcome to the math questions game!");
        int num1 = (int)(Math.random() * 100) + 1; //Create a random number for first num
        int num2 = (int)(Math.random() * 100) + 1; //Create a random number for second num
        int correctAnswer = num1 * num2; //Get the correct answer
        System.out.println("What is " + num1 + " * " + num2); //Display question
        answer = scan.nextInt();  //Scanner will pick up users answer
        if(answer == correctAnswer) { //if the question matches the correct answer, print congrats and continue with the loop.
            System.out.println("Congrats! That is correct");
        }
        else if(answer != correctAnswer) { //If the answer does not match, while the answer is incorrect, continue to prompt the user for the correct answer. 
            while(answer != correctAnswer) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect! Try again.");
                System.out.println("What is " + num1 + " * " + num2);
                answer = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Yes to play again, No to exit: ");
        String keepPlaying = scan.next();
        if(keepPlaying.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) {
            running = false;
        }
    }
```

The first difference is the Boolean value "running". In programming we call this a flag. It will be true or false and keep the program running if we use this flag as the control variable for our while loop so long as the variable is equal to true. Instead of using 1 or 2 in a while loop to see if the user wants to exit, it makes more since to create a flag that is set to true, and then set it to false if the user wants to exit the program at a later date. As you can see, if the user enters "No", meaning they don't want to keep playing, we set running to false, which will break us out of the loop. The second issue is that you create multiple scanner objects which can be inefficient. When you keep multiple scanner objects open, this can reduce memory. As you can see from my sample, we only need ONE Scanner object to execute this code. We COULD in theory use multiple Scanners and close() each Scanner after we use it, which could be efficient in terms of memory usage, but would require writing more code. In a small program such as this we can just use one Scanner object as you can see here. We will call it scan. Lastly, we will set the initial answer to 0.

We start our while loop. while(running) will keep the loop running so long as running is set =  to true. We will then welcome the user and then we will create random variables as you did in your code for the first number to multiply and the second number to multiply. We then create a variable for correctAnswer. Here is a key point... We then prompt the user to enter the answer, but we use the same scanner object that we created earlier. We have no need to create another one. If the answer and the correctAnswer are not equal to each other, we create a while loop to prompt the user for the correct answer, and we USE THE SAME SCANNER object that we already created instead of creating another one. This is the crux of the biggest change from your code. Your code at this point says:

```
if(input != answertrue)
{
    System.out.println("Sorry try again");
    System.out.printf("%d*%d=", number1,number2);
    input = sc.nextInt();

}
```

But this will simply test to see if the answer is correct or not. It will then print the sorry message, print the message again, and then store input as that value. This doesn't work in this scenario and you instead need to utilize a while loop in your method such as the one I highlighted. Then to get the user to exit we can prompt the user to enter Yes or No and USE THE SAME SCANNER OBJECT that we have been using the entire time. If the user enters "No" or "no" we will set running equal to false, and the program will exit.

Answer (score 1):

For a start you have to put both if(exit)-conditions inside the while-loop. That way you get proper validation checking of the input that user gives.

To answer you question, your code actually accepts the user input but it does the checking of the answer only once. It doesn't check after a wrong answer. That's why you will need a while-loop like this:

```
while(input!=answertrue)
{
    System.out.println("Sorry try again");
    System.out.printf("%d*%d=", number1,number2);
    input = sc.nextInt();
}
```